# Proving that a certain function approaches a certain limit at a certain point using epsilon-delta method (Proof Check)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to prove that,

$\lim_{x\to 1}$ $\frac{x}{x+1}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$

using delta-epsilon method.

My answer: Let $\epsilon$ > $0$ and let $\delta$ = min( 1 , 2$\epsilon$)

Then,  $\left|\frac{x}{x+1} - \frac{1}{2}\right|$ = $\left|x - 1\right|\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{1}{x+1}\right|$

Since $\left|x-1\right| < 1$ implies that $0 < x < 2$

which, in turn implies that $\frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{x+1} < 1$

So the result follows, $\left|x - 1\right|\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{1}{x+1}\right| < \epsilon$

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are in your studies/class, more justification around some of these conclusions could be helpful for the sake of clarity. For example, writing:

$$\Big|\frac{x}{x+1} - \frac{1}{2}\Big| = \Big|\frac{2x}{2(x+1)} - \frac{x+1}{2(x+1)}\Big| = \Big|\frac{x-1}{2(x+1)}\Big| = \frac{1}{2}\Big|x-1\Big|\Big|\frac{1}{x+1}\Big|$$

Or, looking to the next line, that: $|x - 1| < 1$ means $-1 < x - 1 < 1$; so, we have $0<x<2$.

Similarly, this final inequality is equivalent to $1 < x+1 < 3$, whence

$$\frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{x+1} < 1$$

as claimed. Acceptable proof writing is, to a nontrivial extent, a function of the reader.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On a problem set and exam I would give the exact same amount of detail as you suggested. I guess my main goal here was to find out if I was right for sure.